# Why isn't site rendering as responsive when using Bootstrap in aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a page here where I'm running Bootstrap (via CDN) on an aspx page. I'm able to run bootstrap just fine in desktop. However, in mobile, it is not responsive.

Page: http://ecommerce.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/confreg/default.aspx

[image]

I've tried calling the Bootstrap core files locally, too, and nothing's working.

Everything is tucked into a webform. I'm calling all the classes via JavaScript objects.

```
    var j = document.getElementById("jval").value;
    var obj = JSON.parse(j);


    var DivCont = document.getElementById("DivCont");



    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        var d = new Date(obj[i].StartDate);
        var sd = d.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear();
        var t = "";

        //alert(obj[i].ProdId)
        t += "<div class=\"row\">";
        t += "<div class='col-sm-12'>";
        t += "<div class='card no-bg no-border'>";
        t += "<div class='row'>";
        t += "<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-12'>";

        t += "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
        t += "<li class=\"list-group-item date no-bg no-border text-uppercase\">";
        t += "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> Start Date: " + sd;
        t += "</li>";
        t += "<li class='list-group-item time no-bg no-border text-uppercase'>";
        t += "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> Type: " + obj[i].SessionType;
        t += "</li>";
        t += "<li class='list-group-item speaker no-bg no-border text-uppercase'>";
        t += "<i class='fa fa-user'></i> Speaker: " + obj[i].LblName;
        t += "</li>";
        t += "</ul>";
        t += "</div>";
        t += "<div class='col-lg-9 col-sm-12'>";
        t += "<h4 class='card-header title-mlr-0 no-bg no-border text-black text-uppercase mt-3 mb-3'>";
        t += obj[i].SessionName;
        t += "</h4>";
        t += "<p class='card-text'>";
        t += obj[i].ShortDescr;
        t += "</p>";
        t += "</div>";

        t += "</div></div></div></div>";
        //alert(t)
        DivCont.innerHTML += t;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some required meta tags in `<head>`. From the Bootstrap getting started [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag):

> Bootstrap is developed mobile first, a strategy in which we optimize
>   code for mobile devices first and then scale up components as
>   necessary using CSS media queries. To ensure proper rendering and
>   touch zooming for all devices, add the responsive viewport meta tag to
>   your .

Add the following meta tags to `<head>` to help ensure the page is responsive. You would most likely add this to your Master Template `<%@ Master ... %>`.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That worked. That's what I get for trying to shift between being a front end dev to a back end dev. Thanks.